# Flex: How do you apply a style (from an external CSS) within the init/constructor of a custom as3 component?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I had a custom MXML component, that I have converted to a pure AS3 component that extends Canvas. I took the stylings i.e. alpha, color etc. from the MXML and added them to a .css file under /src/assets/.

My question is, how do I apply these styles within the custom AS3 component i.e. constructor or init()?

I read that you declare the style source only in your MainApp.mxml using `<mx:Style source="assets/css/swimlaneStyle.css"/>`. If so, then how do I then apply it?

The .css example is below

```
/* CSS file */

Canvas.roundedCanvasYellow{ 
    backgroundColor:#ffffcc; 
    cornerRadius:5; 
    dropShadowEnabled:true;
    dropShadowColor:#2A2929;
    borderStyle:solid;
    borderThickness:0; 
    backgroundAlpha:0.9;    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be as straight forward as doing:

```
this.styleName = "roundedCanvasYellow"
```

(I've used `this.` in my example just to make it clear, you usually wouldn't include that in your real code).

Or when you create in instance of your component programmatically do `instance.styleName = "roundedCanvasYellow"`, or if you create an instance in mxml just set the `styleName` attribute as normal.

Comment: Spot on. That worked. It doesnt work if I leave in the Canvas keyword: this.styleName="Canvas.roundedCanvasYellow". 

I see now that once the styleSheet is registered in the MainApp, its then accessible to the other classes, sweet.

Answer (score -1):

I think this works well when you use `this.styleName="roundedCanvasYellow"` instead of `this.styleName="Canvas.roundedCanvasYellow"`.